# What is the difference between nodejs clustering+domains vs PM2?

Tags: node.js, pm2

NodeJS has **its own modules** for managing clustering and process restart:

- [clustering module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) which allows node to run multiple processes based on the # of cores in the machine. This will also spawn new processes when old ones shutdown.
- [domain module](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) allows node to stop taking requests and shutdown the processes after an error has occurred.

Then there's **PM2**, and I've seen guides [like this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) saying that PM2 allows for logging, some stats monitoring, process restart, and clustering for nodejs.

Other than the stats monitoring and logging, can someone explain what the difference between the two is? Are they supposed to be used together or do I pick one or the other?

In a production environment, how does each fare in shutting down + restarting on bootup for the nodejs app:

- System needs to restart (applying system patches, etc)
- Restarting all nodejs processes to apply new code changes on server.

Answer (score 0):

PM2 uses cluster under the hood, and the makes the whole cluster management easier. For your requirements, you want to look at PM2.